# NHibernate Mapping by Code OneToOne: does not works with unique key

Tags: nhibernate

I have two entities:

```
public class ServiceEvent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    **public virtual Customer CustomerRef { get; set; }**

    public long ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    **public virtual ServiceEvent Event { get; set; }**

    public string TestCustomer { get; set; }
    public long CustonerId { get; set; }
}
```

and mappings:

```
    public ServiceEventMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.Native));
        Property(x => x.ServiceId, m => {m.Unique(true); m.NotNullable(true);});
        Property(x => x.Test);
        OneToOne(x => x.CustomerRef, m => m.PropertyReference(typeof(Customer).GetPropertyOrFieldMatchingName("Event")));
    }

    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.Native));
        Property(x => x.CustonerId);
        Property(x => x.TestCustomer);
        ManyToOne(x => x.Event, m =>
        {
            m.PropertyRef("ServiceId");
            m.Column(mc =>
            {
                mc.Name("service_id");
                mc.NotNullable(true);
            });
            m.ForeignKey("fk_service_event_customer");
        });
    }
```

I have used an example from [NOtherDev](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-onetoone.html). As is it described in example, I have made many-to-one relation on one side and "virtual" one-to-one relation on the other side.

It works fine in case when primary keys have the same values in both tables. But I need this relation to be based on `ServiceId` field, not primary key.

Currently I have a problem with selection of the data. All `ServiceEvent` objects that are read from database has `null` in `CustomerRef` property.

I have following data in database:

**customer table**

id |service_id |test_customer |custoner_id

7  |55         |test string   |444534543

**service_event table**

id |service_id |test

2  |55         |another string

When I'm reading `Customer` it has proper link to `ServiceEvent` object.

It seems that `PropertyReference` setting in one-to-one mapping simply doesn't work.

Please help me to find out where is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

One to one relations *always* share the primary key, if that wasn't the case, you could have several entities related to the same. In one of the entities (the dependent), it is both the primary and the foreign key, and in the other (the primary) it is just the primary key.